# How to Minimize and suspend the app (and continue when restored)?

Tags: javascript, nwjs

I have the following piece of code for my desktop app:

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
gui.App.registerGlobalHotKey(new gui.Shortcut(
  {
    key: "Alt+Tab",
    active: function ()
    {
      gui.Window.get().minimize();
      gui.Window.get().blur();
    }
  }
));
```

This does not work unless I change `key` to something else. I'm not specifically looking for a *hotkey* solution, it's just that this way app continues automatically when restored. I am, however looking for (preferably) a solution that does not require additional modules.

P.S. Bonus question: does NW.js allow creating app-wide hotkeys?

Answer (score 0):

I, actually, rushed with this question. The solution for me was just one line:

`gui.Window.get().on('blur', function() {gui.Window.get().minimize();});`